# Differences in assigning on-stage or code-created object instances to stage.focus?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to focus on a button(a MovieClip) with up/over/down/disabled effects and I am facing the following issue.

When I specifically place an instance of the MovieClip to the stage and name it properly, I can then simply assign that MovieClip to stage.focus and when I export the .swf file, the MovieClip is present on the scene with the down animation visible.

I am trying to create a few of those buttons on the fly. However, when I create an instance of that button (and of course add it to the scene) by writing code and then assign that newly created button instance to stage.focus, the instance is visible on the scene, but the up animation is visible instead of the down animation.

I tried using gotoAndStop() to manually get the instance to show down animation, before assigning it to stage.focus, but that way the down animation is not fixed, and when I get my mouse on and off of the object without any clicking.

What may be the reason, and more importantly, the solution to this issue? How can I get down animation to be persistently visible?

The code below is what I wrote in the frame to create the button instance and assign focus to it. When I manually put an instance on the stage, I just used the last line of the code below, after naming the instance someBtn, of course.

```
var someBtn = new SomeButton();
addChild(someBtn);
someBtn.x = 500;
someBtn.y = 500;
someBtn.visible = true;
stage.focus = someBtn;
```

Comment: I suspect there is a foul-up in your button's creation/assignment logic. Could we see the code?

Comment: @ouflak I added the code to the question. Pretty standard piece of code, I think. Not sure if anything could cause any issues.

Comment: Have you tried tracing stage.focus per frame to see if there's a difference?

Comment: show the code for your `SomeButton` class.  You're up/over/down states are frames of it's timeline?